# Why would the voltage at node X and P jump to infinity?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, analog, charge, switched-capacitor

This is an excerpt from Razavi, Chapter 12 (Switched Capacitor Circuits) where he explains the benefits of turning off the switch S2 slightly before S1 (Fig 3), and how that helps the capacitor be unaffected by the charge injected by S1. To this point he explains how after S2 is turned off (Fig 1), if charge injected by S1 is q1, and input capacitance of opamp is ignored, the voltage at X and P jump to infinity. I did not quite understand how this occurs. Can you help me understand?
[image: Fig 1]
[image: Fig 2]

[image: Fig 3]

Comment: I guess it's because opening S2 makes X no longer a virtual ground. WHen he says the Vx and Vp jump to infinite, I think he just means it's floating (which assumes infinite input impedance for the op-amp).

Comment: Hi @DKNguyen, thanks for your response. Yes, X is no longer virtual ground so I understand why the voltage at that point can go anywhere, but why would P jump to infinity? Is that just another way of saying P could be anything because there is no charge sharing?                


I just saw your edit..yes I took it to mean floating too. I did not understand the "infinity" part. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> input capacitance of
> opamp is ignored, the voltage at X and P jump to infinity

For an ideal Op Amp...

If \$ Z_{in-} =  ∞\$  and \$I_C=C\cdot dV/dt = V_{in-}/Z_{in-}\$
then \$ V_{In-} = Z_{in-}\cdot CdV/dt=  ∞\$

Comment: This makes lot of sense! Makes me wonder why I did not see things this way before. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey Tony, if the op amp is not ideal can we measure a stray capacitance in the circuit? If yes, then where in the circuit will that capacitance be?

Comment: Hey @Carl Measurement in-circuit gets lumped and needs to be done with very expensive FET buffered differential probes or RLC meter probes after calibration.  So it's better to see the effects in the design stage and validate in the response stage , unless it's obviously large. e.g. depending on trace geometry like width*length/gap about 2 to 3 cm per pF over a ground plane or between conductors. SATURN PCB design. exe helps compute there.  then datasheet input capacitance for IC's and Ciss. Coss for FETs

Comment: Also if you are grounded and hold your finger a mm near a sensitive part that's something like 1 pF more or less and touch a pair of test pins like 1/4W R wire added for temporary use with your fingertips is something like adding 100 pF per pin for sig & gnd. that increases with area.

Comment: so for example a XTAL osc design with 12 pF caps over a ground plane will radiate less but have more parasitic pF due to the gnd plane. and lower f by a few ppm.  but might not be a problem either way but depends on risetime and design of antenna effects

Comment: you can also simulate the effects. Falstad browser simulator has ideal OA's with fixed gain. then if you add pF to an ideal voltage source in  //   you need to include some series R or ESR but then can see the effects immediately on a  sawtooth or ideal pulse edge

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Alright, I think I understand a bit of what you are saying but not all of it. Thanks for the elaboration. And one last thing. I see on your page that you link to a book by Bob Pease, and I, out of curiosity, wanted to ask if you knew him in real life or had spoken with him while he was still alive?

Comment: He was a couple years before me but my discoveries were somewhat like his, but I read every EDN magazine published before I graduated and every National Semi application book in our library ,the year after at work. Although I did visit/work in Santa Clara for Burroughs/Memorex/Unisys during the '80's and was offered QA Mgr job at Seagate, I never met RAP.  There are a few who have in the google electronics newsgroups that are more prolific than I.

Comment: I was also lucky to have a mentor smarter than RAP , Bill Whitehead. when I first started. Then he told me I wasn't his 1st choice and I didn't always follow his direction which pissed him off.  but that was because I was ashamed to  admit I didn't know how to make a 0.01 Hz PLL back in the mid '70's with lower leakage than PU caps. And it took me a couple weeks to figure out  how to MUX impedances of baseband audio, 2 way high speed SCADA with synchronous data and TV RF onto 1 coax.  I had a lot to learn.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 It sounds like you have a lot of good stories from your time as an EE. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

> if charge injected by S1 is q1, and **input capacitance of opamp is**
> **ignored**, the voltage at X and P jump to infinity. I did not quite
> understand how this occurs. Can you help me understand?

The formula for voltage produced by charge q on a capacitor of value C is V = q/C. If C = 0 then any charge injected into the capacitor (op amp input) will produce infinite voltage.

In practice the injected charge is not totally independent of the voltage. In the case of a FET analog switch the injected charge is produced by the voltage step on the Gate when the FET is turned off. So the op amp input won't jump to infinity, but just go up/down to the voltage step transferred through the FET's Gate-Drain capacitance.

The advantage of opening switch S2 first is that instead of C<sub>H</sub> absorbing charge injected by the opening of S1 it simply jumps to the voltage on S1 when it is opened, so no charge is injected into C<sub>H</sub> (assuming op amp input capacitance and S2 opened capacitance is 0).